# how to get value in multi rows

Tags: javascript, regex

```
 var imput =         function({
                            a: "val",
                            b: "${version}",
                            c: ["c"],
                            d: [],
                            e: [],
                            controls: ["con1,"con2",
                             "con3"
                            ],
                            elements: []
            });
```

I want to get the value of controls "con1,con2.con3
I tried this pattern

```
 .*controls.*\[(.*)\]
```

it worked when all the controls were in one line
How I can do it if the value is in seperated lines ?

Comment: `"` after `con1` missed

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense at all. Even if you fix the missing `"`, the code is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
controls\s*:\s*\[([\s\S]*?)\]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/IgOc0ii7-qEWiNCz)

Answer (score 1):

`.` means *any character except newline*. Normally you'd have to activate the `s` (*singleline*) option to make it do what you want, but this isn't available in JS.

A workaround is to replace `.` with something like `[\s\S]`, which means: *any character that is either a whitespace, or is not a whitespace*, which is the same as *any character*.

End result (slightly improved):

```
controls\s*:\s*\[([\s\S]*?)\]
```

Note that I used an ungreedy quantifier so that the pattern stops as soon as it encounters a `]`.

You could even make this simpler:

```
controls\s*:\s*\[([^\]]*)\]
```

`[^\]]` means *any character except `]`*.